# Calculating Correlation Coefficient R

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

[Question Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi0wE.p)

To calculate a correlation coefficient, we need information such as the standard deviation of the X and Y plots. However in the above case I am given some output but not sure how to interpret it. I do notice it says "R squared" and has a numeric value next to it, but the question does say "compute", so I'm not sure if this is a trick or I am misinterpreting (most likely this)

If anyone can help it'd be great thanks

Answer (score 1):

Link is dead. Question makes little sense without it. Here is possibly relevant information.

The correlation $r$ must lie in the interval $(-1,1).$ It shows the direction and strength of the linear component of association. The coefficient of determination $r^2$ shows the strength of the linear component of association without showing the direction; it must lie in the interval $(0, 1)$. In some software, especially in regression procedures, $r^2$ is printed as $R^2$ or `R-sq`. If you know $r^2$ and you have a plot of the data so that you can see whether the association is positive or negative, you can take the square root
of $r^2$ and affix the correct sign to get $r.$